# Difference between UL and Non UL PCB

Tags: pcb

I observe two identical PCB except the UL logo mark on them , one has UL mark but other don't.

What is the difference between them. why dont they print UL logo on both the PCB if both are same.

Comment: You have to have UL approval before you can print the UL logo. So any boards made before the approval process is complete won't be so marked. This may not be the only reason, but it's one.

Comment: Every factory that manufactures items and applies the UL mark must have ongoing regular UL inspections. Items manufactured for sale where a UL mark is not needed will not incur the expense of maintaining the UL inspection program. They may participate in some other program for another region of the world. There is also the possibility they switched to an agency that competes with UL. Other marks are accepted in the USA in place of UL.

Comment: So as a hardware desiger what should i do to gett ul mark on pcb, or this is done by rhe pcb manufacture only.

Comment: As a hardware designer, specify the UL-recognized mark as a requirement to the PCB supplier. Then as part of your effort to get the product listed, the PCB is already UL-recognized and is considered proven at the component level. Otherwise, your effort of getting UL-listed includes processing the UL requirements on the bare PCB as if you are the fabricator/manufacturer. As an example, that would include tracking of the raw PCB material from its origin, which is quite impractical for you who are just buying it and using it at an assembly level.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in comments, UL marking requires that the components are UL certified. Or, in this instance, UL *recognized* which means they are components meant to be used as a part of UL listed product. Difference between UL *listing* and *recognition* is that the latter is a relatively lightweight process.

You don't need to use UL recognized parts to get UL listed and using UL recognized parts does not mean your product is UL compliant by default. Usually UL recognition includes some caveats on how the parts need to be installed, assembled, used etc.

In order to "get" that UL recognized marking, you have to fork a lot of money and effort towards UL. They're essentially a tax towards electronics in US market. Fortunately there are other certificates that are acceptable (CB by TÜV) so UL does not get away with murder like it once could. Instead it just gets a small fine and a bit of community service.

Similarly to get UL listed means you provide your product samples to UL who charges you a lot of money and gives (or not) a certificate your product isn't going to electrocute someone, catch fire etc. This is similar to the CE marking except that consumer goods CE marking can be done by "manufacturer's declaration", which you can pull out of thin air. But that may mean jail time if your product kills someone or burns their house down. For regulated fields such as medical and industrial, formal CE testing with recognized organisation (notified body) is required. For medical devices you also have to have a quality system which is audited regularly.

Answer (score 0):

PCB manufacture has to take care of UL marking on PCB, you just have to tell them to make PCB as per UL standard,